# Variância negativa no R? Propagação de erro em ponto flutuante

Tags: r, ponto-flutuante, análise-numérica, variância

Suponha a seguinte fórmula para calcular a variância:

```r
variancia <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  (1/(n^2-n))*(n*(sum(x^2))-(sum(x)^2))
}
```

Veja que ela é equivalente à função `var` na maior parte dos casos:

```r
teste <- 1:5
var(teste)
[1] 2.5
variancia(teste)
[1] 2.5
all.equal(var(teste),variancia(teste))
[1] TRUE
```

Ou neste outro exemplo:

```r
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(100, 10, 100)
var(x1)
[1] 8067.621
variancia(x1)
[1] 8067.621
all.equal(variancia(x1), var(x1))
[1] TRUE
```

Entretanto, no caso abaixo, ela resulta em um valor impossível (valor negativo):

```r
set.seed(1)
x2 <- runif(1000) + 10^12
variancia(x2)
[1] -140878367
var(x2)
[1] 0.08316728
```

Por que a diferença entre as duas funções? Como assegurar que a função `variancia` obtenha o valor correto no último exemplo?

Comment: 10^12 não extrapola o maior inteiro representável em R?

Comment: No caso não são inteiros, são pontos flutuantes do tipo double. Eles têm 64 bits, 1 para o sinal, 11 para o expoente e 52 para o significante, o que dá uma precisão de aproximadamente 16 dígitos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A sua função foi vítima do [cancelamento catastrófico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancelamento_catastr%C3%B3fico). Isso pode acontecer quando se subtrai dois números próximos e de mesmo sinal, no caso da sua função:

```r
sum(x2^2)
[1] 1e+27

sum(x2)^2 / length(x2)
[1] 1e+27
```

No caso da fórmula usada na função `variancia` isso ocorre normalmente quando a variância do vetor é muito menor que sua média.

Vou propor duas soluções pouco eficientes, mas simples:

- Utilize outra fórmula:

```r
variancia2 <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  media <- mean(x)
  sum((x - media)^2) / (n - 1)
}

variancia2(x2)
[1] 0.08316728
```

- Utilize a sua fórmula, mas retire antes a média do vetor, isso não altera o valor da variância.

```r
variancia(x2 - mean(x2))
[1] 0.08316727
```

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do Marcos Banik.

Um número do ponto flutuante do tipo double (64 bits) pode ser, grosso modo, resumido em 3 partes:

*Ponto flutuante tipo double:* ***sinal (1bit), ordem de magnitude (11 bits) e precisão (52 bits)***

Isso dá para representar ordens de magnitude de cerca de `10^308` mas com uma precisão de cerca de `16` dígitos (detalhes sobre como o pacote base do `R` lida com números podem ser vistos na ajuda `?.Machine`), além disso números irracionais ou cujo denominador não sejam potência de 2 são aproximados.

Então veja que um número muito grande pode ser representado pelo `double`, mas não com tanta precisão. Isto pode gerar grandes problemas com operações como soma e subtração. Os números calculados na fórmula `variancia` são da ordem de `(10^12)^2=10^24` no terceiro exemplo, e só temos 52 bits para representar dígitos significantes (os demais são imprecisos). Quando subtraímos um do outro, eliminamos os  "dígitos bons" e só sobram os "dígitos ruins", causando o resultado absurdo.

Uma forma de solucionar o problema é buscar algoritmos mais estáveis para ponto flutuante, como os que o Marcos propôs. Mas supondo que isso não seja possível, você pode utilizar [números de precisão arbitrária.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

No `R` o pacote [Rmpfr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) (Multiple Precision Floating-Point Reliable) fornece números com precisão arbitrária (ao custo de gastar mais memória e tempo de execução, então dependendo do seu computador e do problema, nem sempre é possível).

Então, caso não fosse possível de alguma forma melhorar o algoritmo de cálculo da fórmula `variancia`, poderíamos utilizar o `Rmpfr`. Precisaríamos de mais de 30 dígitos de precisão, o que daria mais de `log2(10^30)=99.65` bits. Arredondando para 128 bits:

```r
library(Rmpfr)
x2.mpfr <- mpfr(x2, 128)
variancia(x2.mpfr)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
[1] 0.0831672741323709434253943823576340475867
```